# How to select an item from a combobox inside grid control in xaml windows 8 App?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, devexpress

I am developing an windows 8 App in which I have placed a combobox inside dev express windows8 grid control.I can populate the Date for the combobox and I can save the selectionitem in database. But when I am loading it again the previously selected value in the combo box is not getting defaulted.

```
<DataTemplate >
   <ComboBox x:Name="cNumber" SelectedValuePath="id" DisplayMemberPath="value"
   SelectedValue="{Binding Path=AreaSeq, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="cNumber_Loaded_1" 
   Height="30" Width="60" Tag="{Binding AreaId}" 
   Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}"
   SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1" />
</DataTemplate>
```

In Loaded function I am populating my grid and in selectionchanged I am storing its value.

Comment: <DataTemplate >                                                            <ComboBox x:Name="cNumber" SelectedValuePath="id" DisplayMemberPath="value" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=AreaSeq, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="cNumber_Loaded_1" Height="30" Width="60" Tag="{Binding AreaId}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1" />  </DataTemplate>

Comment: I tried the above one but its not working